# Magento admin not saving any configuration

Tags: php, magento

Suddenly having problem with saving options in magento backend. I tried all possible ways. Also i noticed on frontend when i log in and click on my cart or on index page it automatically logs out. i am currently using hostgator server and it all happend all of sudden.

1. cleared cache
2. disabled cache
3. no error reported in system.log
4. changed php version
5. changed htaccess

Here is my exception.log file

```
2015-12-10T06:54:12+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1149326' for key 'PRIMARY'' in /home/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /home1/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /home1/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /home1/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /home1/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /home1/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `lo...', Array)
#5 /home1/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(389): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `lo...', Array)
#6 /home1/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(574): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `lo...', Array)
#7 /home1/app/code/core/Mage/Log/Model/Resource/Visitor.php(241): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('log_quote', Array)
#8 /home1/app/code/core/Mage/Log/Model/Resource/Visitor.php(116): Mage_Log_Model_Resource_Visitor->_saveQuoteInfo(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor))
#9 /home1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(458): Mage_Log_Model_Resource_Visitor->_afterSave(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor))
#10 /home1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor))
#11 /home1/app/code/core/Mage/Log/Model/Visitor.php(188): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#12 /home1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1299): Mage_Log_Model_Visitor->saveByRequest(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#13 /home1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1280): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor), 'saveByRequest', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#14 /home1/app/Mage.php(416): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#15 /home1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(534): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#16 /home1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php(70): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->postDispatch()
#17 /home1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(424): Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action->postDispatch()
#18 /home1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('noRoute')
#19 /home1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#20 /home1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(347): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#21 /home1/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#22 /home1/index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
#23 {main}

Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1149326' for key 'PRIMARY'' in /home1/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234
Stack trace:
#0 /home1/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home1/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home1/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home1/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `lo...', Array)
#4 /home1/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(389): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `lo...', Array)
#5 /home1/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(574): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `lo...', Array)
#6 /home1/app/code/core/Mage/Log/Model/Resource/Visitor.php(241): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('log_quote', Array)
#7 /home1/app/code/core/Mage/Log/Model/Resource/Visitor.php(116): Mage_Log_Model_Resource_Visitor->_saveQuoteInfo(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor))
#8 /home1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(458): Mage_Log_Model_Resource_Visitor->_afterSave(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor))
#9 /home1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor))
#10 /home1/app/code/core/Mage/Log/Model/Visitor.php(188): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#11 /home1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1299): Mage_Log_Model_Visitor->saveByRequest(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#12 /home1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1280): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor), 'saveByRequest', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#13 /home1/app/Mage.php(416): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#14 /home1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(534): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#15 /home1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php(70): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->postDispatch()
#16 /home1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(424): Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action->postDispatch()
#17 /home1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('noRoute')
#18 /home1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#19 /home1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(347): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#20 /home1/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#21 /home1/index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
#22 {main}
```

Comment: What options you are trying to save that are not working ? Can you explain little more

Comment: @qaisar in system > configuration all options are not working.  in cms when i make changes it says the changes have been saved but it doesn't and more thing the message shows repeatedly

Comment: check the `var/log` foldr for the errors.

Comment: @MahmoodRehman  can i show you the exception.log file ? also is it possible here to link to the file?

Comment: @user1987049 you can paste in your question.

Comment: Yes add log files on your question area.

Answer (score 0):

If everything else work correctly (except data saving) then you should check if there are no redirects on the data submissions to server.  Most time the problem is caused by bad url rewrite rules in the .htaccess

Comment: Judge from your log data, you should truncate 'log_visitor*' tables.
What was done before this problem?

Comment: does this table means anything for saving options? done nothing it was working fine not even installed any new modules  instead i disabled few and rechecked but problem still persists

Comment: If no changes has been done and the data saving stopped working then the problem can be in server. What are you trying to save? The data saving does not work everywhere or only in some places (like attribute options). Did you check if you don't have post request redirects?

Comment: i don't have post request redirects and its not about only attribute. all fields with input or select option does not work. even cms page data not getting saved when clicking save page or configuration

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your valuable time and help. i would like to tell i finally fixed it.

I removed local.xml in app/etc and on frontend reconfigured magento installation. i kept the old database and magically the problem goes away. still don't know what was the issue but it worked!

Comment: It mean that something was changed in the source code ;)